# Insert line break if Regex pattern found

Tags: php, regex

I have a paragraph which is not formatted. I want to find patterns in the paragraph and format it by inserting line breaks before every next occurrence of the pattern. I am struggling to form the regex patterns and I am not able to figure out the logic to place the line breaks.

```
        $txt=$_POST['wtfb'];
        $re1='((?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Sept|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?))'; # Month 1
        $re4='.*?'; # Non-greedy match on filler
        $re5='(:)'; # Any Single Character 1

        if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1.$re4.$re5."/is", $txt, $matches))
        {
            $month1=$matches[1][0];
            $c1=$matches[2][0];
            echo 'Match';  // Instead of Match, I want to echo the formatted paragraph
        }
        else 
        { 
            echo 'No match'; 
        }
```

Input will be like:

```
May 1, 9:17 AM - Jef23: Hey bro. Jeff hereMay 1, 9:18 AM - $tella2: Could you help me
```

Output will be like:

```
May 1, 9:17 AM - Jef23: Hey bro. Jeff here
May 1, 9:18 AM - $tella2: Could you help me
```

UPDATE: Line break part is done. Figuring out the regex is getting on my nerves. It must detect the pattern of Month, Space, Date, Comma, Comma Character, Time, Space, Hyphen, Space, A string of characters with numbers, alphabets and special characters ending with colon. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Do you need `$c1` and `$month1` for something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

```
<?php
    $input = 'May 1, 9:17 AM - Jef23: Hey bro. Jeff hereMay 1, 9:18 AM - $tella2: Could you help me';
    $output = trim(preg_replace('/(((?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Sept|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?))\s\d+,\s\d+:\d+\s[A|P]M\s-\s[^:]+)/is', "\n$1", $input));
    echo '<pre>', $output, '</pre>';
?>
```

> May 1, 9:17 AM - Jef23: Hey bro. Jeff here
>   May 1, 9:18 AM - $tella2: Could you help me

This gives the desired output. You maybe don't need to match for the username so you could omit `\s[^:]+`.

**OLD**

There you go. I just search for the month + number + ":" pattern and insert a \n before.

```
<?php
    $input = "May 1: Hi, this is JeffMay 1: Hi, this is StellaMay 1: How are you?";
    $output = trim(preg_replace('/(((?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Sept|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?))\s\d+:\s)/i', "\n$1", $input));
    echo '<pre>', $output, '</pre>';
?>
```

> May 1: Hi, this is Jeff
>   May 1: Hi, this is Stella
>   May 1: How are you?

Comment: And how will OP able to get `$c1` and `$month1` ?

Comment: He didn't ask for `$c1` and `$month1` but for a formatted output. If you have a look at his post he says *Instead of Match, I want to echo the formatted paragraph*, thus he wanted to use these variables for outputting the correct format, which he doesn't need with my solution.

Comment: Yes the output, but I think he assigned the variables above for a reason.

Comment: Maybe, but let's just wait for his comments and see what he says. If he needs those variables he should've given us more information.

Comment: This works, although the Regex I am looking for is slightly different. I am updating the question, hang on.